# Can I control the apparent size of a circle marker when the map is zoomed out?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to draw many circle markers on a map that will be zoomed out significantly. I'd like the circles to be smaller than what is visible when the radius is set to 1.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7000; i += 1) {
  L.circle(getRandomLatLng(), {
    color: 'red',
    fillColor: '#f03',
    fillOpacity: 0.1,
    radius: 0.1, // setting this below 1 doesn't make the circles smaller when the map is zoomed out
  }).addTo(map);
}
```

I know that the value of a radius is the radius of the circle in meters, so it's obvious that the size of the marker is directly tied to this value. I'd like to change this behaviour, because in my application, the map will always be shown zoomed-out. Is there a way to control the apparent size of the rendered DOM elements, perhaps with some CSS? If not, can I somehow draw points that are smaller?

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/8o6gd9cm/

Comment: Are you looking to set the size in pixels? You might have missed `L.CircleMarker`.

Comment: Setting the stroke to 0 helps make the rendered circle smaller, but a radius of 1 is still as low as you can go, with a `L.circle`, it seems.

Comment: @IvanSanchez you are right. Please write this as an asnwer, I will gladly accept it.